# Android - как скрыть уведомление о входящих смс?

Tags: java, android, sms

Как программно скрыть определенные входящие смс? Чтобы не было видно уведомления, но сама смс сохранялась при этом во входящих.

Установка приоритета `android:priority="100"` не помогает.

Answer (score 4):

Надо задекларировать ресивер бродкаста на получение SMS, примерно так:

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      this.abortBroadcast();
   }
}
```

Не забыть декларацию в манифесте:

```
<!-- SMS receiver -->
    <receiver
        android:name=".SmsReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS" >
        <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647" > <!-- 999 is highest system priority, so it's hack 2147483647 -->
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" /> <!-- pre kitkat action -->
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_DELIVER" /> <!-- kitkat action -->
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

**Update**

1. Экшн `SMS_RECEIVED` получает приложение уже по факту получения смс, здесь уже все пост-фактум, то есть уведомление уже будет выставлено дефолтным мессенджером и сохранено в БД. Его перехватывать в общем то бессмысленно
2. Экшн `SMS_DELIVERED` получает только дефолтный мессенджер, при этом уже дефолтный мессенджер ответственен за уведомление и сохранения сообщения.

Соответственно:

Вам надо зарегистрировать свое приложение как дефолтный обработчик СМС сообщений. и ловить `SMS_DELIVERED`, в котором "гасить" уведомления. Сразу предупреждаю это довольно сложно: ваше приложение должно уметь писать, читать, удалять сообщения и т.д. Более-менее полная процедура описана [например здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30127564/how-do-i-set-my-app-as-the-default-sms-app). Но даже это не гарантирует, что приложение ваше будет дефолтным - все равно в конечном итоге, выскочит диалог в котором юзеру будет предложено выбрать, типа:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S. Если интересно, можете посмотреть исходники [приложения DarkSMS](https://github.com/ivanovpv/darksms), написанный при скромном моем участии, в нем весь этот функционал реализован.

Comment: Не работает (сообщения по прежниму видны) ( надо ли в Receive как-то обробатывать смс что бы не было видно уведомления смс?

Comment: Там была туча изменений в API работы с смс, давно уже не копался в этом. Вы уверены. что ресивер срабатывает? Посмотрите в отладчике или в логгере, возможно он не срабатывает, вполне могли изменить `ACTION` и заодно напишите версию Андроида. Если очень надо могу покопаться в документации и своих исходниках...

Comment: Посмотрите на апдейт ответа.